# What does "(scores mapped into 1:m using rounded scores)" from the 1-sample permutation test mean?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I'm trying to do an exact paired permutation test. What does this "mapping" mean?

```
> library(exactRankTests)
> perm.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), paired=TRUE, exact=TRUE)

    1-sample Permutation Test (scores mapped into 1:m using rounded scores)

data:  rnorm(10) and rnorm(10)
T = 6, p-value = 0.1836
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In R `1:m` means $1, \ldots, m$ (the natural numbers between 1 and $m$). Here is what the help page of `perm.test` says.

> If real values `x` or `y` are passed to this function the following applies: if `exact` is true (*i.e.* the sample size is less than 50 observations) and `tol` is not given, the scores are mapped into $\{1, . . . , N\}$, see `pperm` for the details. Otherwise the p-values are computed using `tol`. If the sample size exceeds $50$ observations, the usual normal approximation is used.

So here, the package is just a little verbose and says that it has used the first option, not the second. What is taking place is explained in the help page of `pperm` as it says. You can also see it online [there](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactRankTests/exactRankTests.pdf) (click on `dperm` in the topics).

Briefly, the package uses the Streitberg-Röhmel shift algorithm to compute the distribution of the sum of the scores. Since the algorithm assumes that scores are positive integers, real numbers need to be transformed. Here, $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ are transformed to

$$\lfloor x_i \frac{m}{M}\rfloor,$$

where $M = \max(x_1, \ldots, x_m)$. The distribution of the sum of these scores is computed and compared to the transformed score of the sample.